# Using predict() for a test set with different length compared to training set

Tags: r, predict

I'm training a decision tree model using rpart using the following:

```
model<-rpart(formula, method="class", data=training)
```

Then, I'm using predict with this model on the test dataset:

```
predict(model, newdata=test, type="class")
```

I get the following error when I execute the command above. Note that the training and test datasets are of different lengths.

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object,  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'fsc_perp')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 28935 rows but variables found have 43408 rows
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would guess you have factors with different levels in your test and training data sets.  Make sure you encode all factors in your test set with the same levels as your training set.

Comment: @Andrie All the attributes are numeric except the variable to be predicted, and that has 5 levels in both datasets.

Comment: please post the results of `str(training)` and `str(test)`

Comment: @Moon_Watcher: did u find an answer to this question? Can you tell me if you did?

Comment: @mihirj Honestly, I can't recollect what happened with this. This was a long time back. I'd post the same question again to see if you get any answers.